# Aged inventory schedule using dplyr, cumsum and lag

Tags: r, dplyr, inventory-management

This is my first stackoverflow post after years of passive browsing. I am stuck on this problem and it's driving me nuts! Thanks so much for helping.

I have a data frame of inventory supply and demand bucketed by age. I have collected this data across time for many products. Demand for inventory of a certain age can be met with supply of the same age or younger. I am trying to calculate how much demand can be met with supply within each age bucket, filled youngest to oldest.

The data frame will be large (10^7 rows) so I am trying to do this with `dplyr`, `mutate`, `lag`, and `cumsum` versus a loop, which I suspect will be slow.

Here is a sample group within my data set (product and date groupings omitted):

```
library(dplyr)

Inventory <- data.frame(
  Age = c(90, 120, 270, 365, Inf),
  Demand = c(0, 5000, 25, 5000, 10),
  Supply = c(4000, 50, 4000, 300, 0))

View(Inventory)
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
Result <- Inventory
Result$Start = c(0, 4000, 0, 3975, 0)
Result$In = c(4000, 50, 4000, 300, 0)
Result$Out = c(0, 4050, 25, 4275, 0)
Result$End = c(4000, 0, 3975, 0, 0)
Result$Short = c(0, 950, 0, 725, 10)

View(Result)
```

I applied standard inventory calculations above:

- Start = End
- In = Supply
- Out = min(Demand, Start + In)
- End = Start + In - Out
- Short = Demand - Out

I am having no luck using dplyr, but I think there is a solution using clever combinations of max, min, lag, and cumsum.

Comment: Hi Alex, unfortunately, I think you may have to resort to using a `for()` loop.  Your specific case requires a sort of dual dependency that doesn't really work with `dplyr::` tools. Basically you need "Start" to call the lagged value of "End", but then you have to calculate the next value "End" using the value of "Start", which requires iteration.  My understanding is that `lag()` and `lead()` work assume static values in the a vector and don't handle iteration.  Would you be interested in seeing a solution with a loop anyway?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks so much for the reply. Makes sense. Yes please I'd love to see a solution!! I'm working with groups (product and date) in my data frame, so after looping through one product-date subset, I need to loop across all the groups.

Comment: what is 'End'? cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: @Jinjin read the question again. `End = Start + In - Out`

Comment: @Mark Yeah. I read `End = Start + In - Out`, `Start = End` and `Out = min(Demand, Start + In)`. An infinite loop?

Comment: @Jinjin more or less 

Comment: @Jinjin - sorry for the confusion. In inventory schedules the starting inventory is set to the ending inventory from the previous time period, before considering additions and withdrawals in the current period. So the first bullet should be `Start = lag(End, default = 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If speed becomes an issue over a large number of rows then potentially the fastest way to deal with iterating calculations is via `Rcpp`.

You essentially need a cummulative-sum-but-floored-at-zero function, which adds the Supply - Demand outcome of each day to the last total and zeros it if it's negative. Here's a `cumnominus` trial function which gives the right table and can be used in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

cumnominus <- Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector cumnominus(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  
  NumericVector sumout(n);
  
  sumout[0] = (x[0] < 0) ? 0 : x[0];
  
  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      
      sumout[i] = (x[i] < 0) ? 0 : x[i] + sumout[i - 1];
    
    }
  
  return sumout;
}")

Inventory |> 
  mutate(In = Supply,
         End = cumnominus(Supply - Demand),
         Start = lag(End, default = 0),
         Short = pmax(0, Demand - (Start + Supply)),
         Out = pmin(Demand, Start + In)) |> 
  select(Age, Demand, Supply, Start, In, Out, End, Short)

#>   Age Demand Supply Start   In  Out  End Short
#> 1  90      0   4000     0 4000    0 4000     0
#> 2 120   5000     50  4000   50 4050    0   950
#> 3 270     25   4000     0 4000   25 3975     0
#> 4 365   5000    300  3975  300 4275    0   725
#> 5 Inf     10      0     0    0    0    0    10

Result
#>   Age Demand Supply Start   In  Out  End Short
#> 1  90      0   4000     0 4000    0 4000     0
#> 2 120   5000     50  4000   50 4050    0   950
#> 3 270     25   4000     0 4000   25 3975     0
#> 4 365   5000    300  3975  300 4275    0   725
#> 5 Inf     10      0     0    0    0    0    10
```

As a bit of a test against an R-only loop on a dataframe of 5m rows it takes around 0.05s compared to R-loop of 8.5s:

```r
cumnominus_r <- function(x) {
  out_sum <- integer(length(x))
  out_sum[1] <- max(0, x[1])
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    out_sum[i] <- ifelse(x[i] < 0, 0, out_sum[i - 1] + x[i])
  }
  
  out_sum
}

big_df <- tibble(
  Demand = sample(seq(1000, 6000, 500), 5000000, replace = TRUE),
  Supply = sample(seq(1000, 6000, 500), 5000000, replace = TRUE)
) 


bench::mark(
  Rcpp_fun = big_df |> 
    mutate(End = cumnominus(Supply - Demand)),
  R_only_fun = big_df |> 
    mutate(End = cumnominus_r(Supply - Demand))
)


#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 Rcpp_fun     43.15ms  52.95ms    16.1      77.7MB     8.94
#> 2 R_only_fun     8.59s    8.59s     0.116    95.4MB    20.8
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Andy. This is a massive help. I've never used Rcpp before. Amazing! Slight edit to the C++ function to get this to work for all cases. The zeroing in cumnominus needs to happen when the running sum is negative, not when previous element is negative. Will share revised function in a new answer. Full credit to you!

Comment: Good spot! Hadn't quite thought that through so glad it's a working function now. I think this is the key thing that Rcpp is handy for - customised iterations that don't already have vectorised functions. Hope it's handy in speeding up your code!

Comment: In case you're interested, the base `cumsum` and other cumulative functions are fast vectorised functions because they're written in C and use for loops! (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src%2Fmain%2Fcum.c). Using a C++ loop here in theory mimics this and gives the same efficiency rather than continually breaking out of fast C addition functions to get slow R to trigger next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with using dplyr in this context is as, Sean has stated, to create all of the Start column we'd need the End column, and vice versa. You could potentially do this using `accumulate2()`, but I don't imagine it would be any faster than a for loop.

```
Inventory$In <- Inventory$Supply

for (r in seq_len(nrow(Inventory))) {
  Inventory$Start[r] <- if (r == 1) 0 else Inventory[r - 1, "End"]
  Inventory$Out[r] <- min(Inventory$Demand[r], Inventory$Start[r] + Inventory$In[r])
  Inventory$End[r] <- Inventory$Start[r] + Inventory$In[r] - Inventory$Out[r]
  Inventory$Short[r] <- Inventory$Demand[r] - Inventory$Out[r]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Andy Baxter solved this with an Rcpp function that works in mutate. Slight edit to his function to get it to work in all cases:

```
cumnominus <- Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector cumnominus(NumericVector x) {
  
  int n = x.size();
  
  NumericVector sumout(n);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      
      sumout[i] =  (x[i] + sumout[i - 1]) > 0 ? x[i] + sumout[i - 1] : 0;
    
    }
  
  return sumout;
}")
```

And then the `dplyr::mutate()` steps per Andy's answer.